# How to create a 3d bounding box using stereo cameras

Tags: opencv, image-processing

So I have a setup consisting of multiple stereo camera setups, now I want to use it to get a rough 3d model of objects within the array. I'm quite new to image processing and the like. I was thinking about uisng each stereo camera to get a depth image and remove the background (which is fixed) but I have no iea how to consolidate multiple depth images into one 3d object. I'm not looking for4 high accuracy, I would mainly just like to be able to get the dimensions of an object within this array of these cameras.
Some other questions right now I have two stereo cameras on opposite sides of the object, with a fixed position, would I need more in order to acheive this?
If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be really thankful, because I don't have an idea about what direction to go.
Thank you so much in advance.

TL:DR; Multiple cameras, how to get 3d model of object, does not need to be detailed mainly need the 3d bounding polygon.

Comment: have a look at truncated signed distance function (TSDF). It is well explained in the kinect fusion paper. Should work with multiple depth sensors at a time. If you know the rlative 3D positions of the cameras to each other it should become quite simple.

Comment: another way could be to just use multiple point clouds in a single 3D space, which again is reached by using extrinsics of the cameras (relative to each other). A third approach could be to use 2D perspective homograpies on the depth maps directly, but this will only work for planar scenes or little position difference between cameras.